# difference between user-mode and system-mode in GitLab Runner CI/CD

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

While configuring GitLab runner in system-mode, service is not getting started, but in user-mode the service is working good.

In GitLab runner document they have not briefed the purpose
https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/#super-user-permission

Only difference I understood is the path:

User-mode = /Users/ayufan/.gitlab-runner/config.toml

Sytem-mode =  /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml

Could any one explain, how the results are affected with system-mode.

Update: 
I didnt get the answer from gitlab forums but I reading some notes here https://medium.com/static-object/how-to-set-up-gitlab-ci-for-ios-in-a-few-relatively-simple-steps-56a0d88d0272 , I learned that this an issue that most of them facing.

Comment: Your question is worth to ask, I have given it a vote and I have answered it and explained the difference between system mode and user mode, can you mark it as accepted to reach others?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## User mode vs System mode

In `user mode`, the runners you register will only work for the current user. If you log in from different user the runners will not be available for your pipeline and if you try to run your pipeline, it will be `stuck` cause there are no available runners to work.

In `system mode`, the runners you register will be available to run and work as long as the machine is on regardless of the user you log in from.

## Working in system mode

To register a runner in `system mode`, all you need to do is to prefix your `register` command with `sudo` as following:

```
sudo gitlab-runner register
```

To verify which runners are working in `system mode`:

```
sudo gitlab-runner verify
```

Comment: While this answer is mostly correct, I want to add two points: 1. in user mode, jobs have to be run manually using gitlab-runner run 2. As system mode runs with root permissions, malicious gitlab-ci.yml code can potentially harm your system. Worth mentioning, check out https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/security/